# MySQL SELECT row with maximal similarity

Tags: mysql, sql

Im have table like:

```
id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5
```

How to find row(s) with maximum count equal vals (not all vals have to be equal).
Example: says I have 4 rows in table:

```
1 | Mercedes | E | black | 250hp | 270kmh | 
2 | Mercedes | C | white | 250hp | 240kmh | 
3 | BMW      | C | white | 250hp | 250kmh | 
4 | PORCHE   | E | red   | 300hp | 290kmh |
```

I select:

```
val1=PORCHE val2=E val3=red val4=250 val5=270
```

and get:

```
1 | Mercedes | E | black | 250hp | 270kmh | 
4 | PORCHE   | E | red   | 300hp | 290kmh |
```

because both have 3 equal fields. 
Also question not about cars and I hope make this with one table. 
That table about checking hardware of user and compare if it absolutely equal or how many equal it is

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is thankfully compact - but perhaps too compact to be understood easily. Could you elaborate a little your case, for instance by providing a brief example what you mean with "with maximum count equal vals"? What is the metric to judge your "similarity" (e.g. method of least squares?)?

Comment: Pro tip: Edit your own question to make it better instead of writing an explaining comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution for MySql 8.0+ using `rank()` window function which will return the most matched rows with ties:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    rank() over (order by
      (val1 = 'PORSCHE') + 
      (val2 = 'E') + 
      (val3 = 'red') + 
      (val4 = '250hp') + 
      (val5 = '270km') desc 
    ) rn
  from tablename  
) 
select * from cte
where rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bKLBYZVbZZ2TAN34c4vnAC/1).
And this will work for previous versions but will not return ties, just the 1st best match:

```
select *
from tablename 
order by 
      (val1 = 'PORSCHE') + 
      (val2 = 'E') + 
      (val3 = 'red') + 
      (val4 = '250hp') + 
      (val5 = '270km') desc 
limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRuJsReoEW95arirXLiQJo/4).

Comment: there is what I exactly need based on selected answer https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRuJsReoEW95arirXLiQJo/1 . I need select better similarity table row comprate to query. How to do same with ur solution ? Im don't understand where I input all that data in ur solution.

Comment: For now yes, that's works, I absolutely don't understand how but its work. tnx for now ur solution looks a lot better than previous)

Answer (score 0):

I have re-created your case here locally with the following sample data model:

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `val1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val5` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`, `val5`) VALUES ('1', 'Mercedes', 'E', 'black', '250hp', '270kmh');
INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`, `val5`) VALUES ('2', 'Mercedes', 'C', 'white', '250hp', '240kmh');
INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`, `val5`) VALUES ('3', 'BMW', 'C', 'white', '250hp', '250kmh');
INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`, `val5`) VALUES ('4', 'PORSCHE', 'E', 'red', '300hp', '270kmh');
```

To get your "similarity votes" you could something like this:

```
select id, count(*) as votes from
(
    select id from cars where val1 = 'PORSCHE'
    union all
    select id from cars where val2 = 'E'
    union all 
    select id from cars where val3 = 'red'
    union all
    select id from cars where val4 = '250hp'
    union all
    select id from cars where val5 = '270kmh'
) as votes
group by id
```

With your test data this generates something like this:

```
id  votes
1   3
2   1
3   1
4   4
```

Now comes the tricky part: We only want the "maximal votes" (best fit). The challenge here is that we need to have this votes query above twice: Once to extract the maximum, and the second time for determining the `id`s associated to the maximal votes. If you only wanted the "first best match" you could use an `order by votes desc limit 1`. If you want to get "all ids which have the highest votes", then you could do something like:

```
select * from (
    select id, count(*) as votes from
    (
        select id from cars where val1 = 'PORSCHE'
        union all
        select id from cars where val2 = 'E'
        union all 
        select id from cars where val3 = 'red'
        union all
        select id from cars where val4 = '250hp'
        union all
        select id from cars where val5 = '270kmh'
    ) as votes
    group by id
) hits where votes = (
    select max(votes) from (
        select id, count(*) as votes from
        (
            select id from cars where val1 = 'PORSCHE'
            union all
            select id from cars where val2 = 'E'
            union all 
            select id from cars where val3 = 'red'
            union all
            select id from cars where val4 = '250hp'
            union all
            select id from cars where val5 = '270kmh'
        ) as votes
        group by id
    ) as hits
)
```

Unfortunately, this duplicates the selection query (and also needs to be computed twice). There is large discussion on how to best solve such a problem at [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/6350762).

In your case I would also consider writing "similarity votes" to a [temporary table](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/) (if you expect many rows to be compared). Whether this is appropriate depends on what kind of database access your application has.

Comment: After test I assume ur first solution is best I just add to it "order by votes desc limit 1" and get that exactly what I want ! Thanks again. I get id of row what with maximum similarity and after just select this row by it id.

Comment: @user368470  . . . This is not the best solution.  Unpivoting the data and re-aggregating it is a lot of unnecessary work.  Both forpas and I have alternative solutions which are much more efficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will try use, but im beginner in sql so this solution just easy to use compare to says forpas solution

Comment: @user368470 . . . If you are learning SQL, you should learn how to do things correctly.  Doing unnecessary aggregations and unpivots is not a good habit to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I think this would be the simplest solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (order by (t.val1 = @val1) + (t.val2 = @val2) + (t.val3 = @val3) + (t.val4 = @val4) + (t.val5 = @val5) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In versions of MySQL before version 8, this is a little more complicated, but not that bad:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.val1 = @val1) + (t.val2 = @val2) + (t.val3 = @val3) + (t.val4 = @val4) + (t.val5 = @val5)
     ) = (select max( (t2.val1 = @val1) + (t2.val2 = @val2) + (t2.val3 = @val3) + (t2.val4 = @val4) + (t2.val5 = @val5) )
          from t t2
         );
```

Comment: same question mate. there is what I exactly need based on selected answer db-fiddle.com/f/sRuJsReoEW95arirXLiQJo/1 . I need select better similarity table row comprate to query. How to do same with ur solution ? Im don't understand where I input all that data in ur solution.

Comment: Same question as what?  The values `@val1` and so on are where you put in the constants that you want to compare to.

Comment: Same as question for forpas). For now I understand thanx a lot!